# why $h^{2,0}$ ought to be positive for non-algebraic manifolds?

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

In their paper [``Nonalgebraic hyperkahler manifolds''](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1292940689) Campana, Oguiso and Peternell mention in Theorem 2.3 that if $Y$ is a smooth, Kähler, non-algebraic base of a fibration $f: X \dashrightarrow Y$ then $h^{2,0}(Y) > 0$, quoting Kodaira's paper about what is now known as Kodaira embedding theorem.

What particular consequence of Kodaira embedding, or a fact mentioned in Kodaira's paper, implies this statement?

Comment: What is $X{}{}$? What kind of fibration is this? (Does it play nicely with some geometry or another somehow?)

Comment: It is not clear to me what precisely in teh setting is relevant for the conclusion (at a first read it seems that the only relevant thing is that $Y$ is non-algebraic; but this looks strange). So for the sake of completeness of the picture, here are the assumptions of Theorem 2.3: $X$ is a hyperkahler manifold of dimension $2n$, $h^{2,0}(X)=1$, and $\sigma^n\neq 0$ where $\sigma$ generates $H^0(X,\Omega^2)$, $f: X \dashrightarrow Y$ is a non-trivial meromorphic fibration.

Comment: They use the conclusion ($h^{2,0}(Y) > 0$) to infer that since a pullback of a holomorphic form on $Y$ to $X$ is not of maximal rank, then the fibres of $f$ must be finite, or $Y$ algebraic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $Y$ is Kahler, it has a symplectic form, which cannot be zero in $H^2(Y)$. If $h^{2,0}(Y) = 0$, we see that the Kahler cone (the set of cohomology classes for which there is a Kahler form given the complex structure $J$) is actually open in $H^2(Y)$, as it's of dimension $h^{1,1} \neq 0$. In this open set, therefore, there must be a rational (and hence there must be an integral) cohomology class.  Then by [this form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodaira_embedding_theorem) of the Kodaira embedding theorem, $Y$, equipped with the new Kahler structure, admits a holomorphic embedding into some $\Bbb P^n$, and hence with this Kahler structure it's algebraic. But in changing the Kahler form, we never changed the complex structure, so we can honestly say that the original complex manifold was algebraic. This contradicts our assumption.

Comment: Thanks! So you use the fact that the  Kahler cone is open in $H^{1,1}$. Does this always hold?

Comment: @DimaSustretov Yes, I poorly phrased what I wanted to say there. The point is that $H^2(X;\Bbb Z)$ needn't intersect the Kahler cone unless we have something special happen. In this case, because $H^2(Y;\Bbb R) \cap H^{1,1}(Y) = H^2(Y;\Bbb R)$ (because $H^{1,1}$ is everything!), the Kahler cone is open in $H^2(Y;\Bbb R)$, which is what we used here. But you could in principle have, say, the Kahler cone intersect $H^2(Y;\Bbb R)$ be generated by the symplectic form, which would just be some line with irrational slope (so it never hits $H^2(Y;\Bbb Z)$.)